# If like function for Attribute Table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have this data that is a result of intersections and areal calculations. In the attribute table drawn below, you can see the column `Kelurahan` has many duplicates because the mean prices differ based on the area. So I calculated the `price_weights` to measure price against proportion of area.

How do I simplify this, like add all the `price_weights` for each specific Kelurahan and then have only single Kelurahans?

I want to have one string `price_weight` for Kelurahans. So there is one row of `Ubo-ubo` for instance and the `price_weight` value is `61048,775+141766,763+.....`.

[image]

Please leave a comment if something is unclear.

Comment: Hi yes, that is exactly my question actually. I want to have one string price_weight for kelurahans. So the there is one row of Ubo-ubo for instance and the price_weight value is 61048,775+141766,763+......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to use `sum` function. Open Field Calculator and run this expression:

```
sum( "price_weights", "Kelurahan" )
```

Result:

[image]